# Unable to stream data on IBM Watson IoT quick start even though device is connected

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot

Currently I am testing a connection using IBM Watson IoT quick start to stream the data from my device. I am using a Java SDK to get the data off, and I am running into an issue with visualising the data. The device state is connected, however, no data is displayed on the quick start menu. Please see the following link for the error.

Any clue what might be issue: https://quickstart.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/#/device/b827eb104681/sensor/

Comment: I did a quick test and Quickstart works for me.  Can you include your code?

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that your device state is connected,  but I checked the Watson IoT logs and don't see any connection for device ID b827eb104681 in the past 12 hours.  Provide your code or more info about how you are connecting and have confirmed that your device is connected and sending data.